# `groovyConsole` can not start on Ubuntu 18.04 with java 8, how to fix?

Tags: java, groovy-console

when I run groovyConsole from terminal, it give up with an exception:

```
$ groovyConsole 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:138)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: javax.swing.JMenu.setMnemonic() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [F]
Possible solutions: setMnemonic(char), setMnemonic(int), getMnemonic()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:177)
    at groovy.ui.view.BasicMenuBar$_run_closure1.doCall(BasicMenuBar.groovy:22)
    at groovy.ui.view.BasicMenuBar$_run_closure1.doCall(BasicMenuBar.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.dispatchNodeCall(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:899)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:791)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.invokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:511)
    at groovy.util.FactoryInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1322)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at groovy.ui.view.BasicMenuBar.run(BasicMenuBar.groovy:21)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1181)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at groovy.ui.Console$__clinit__closure25.doCall(Console.groovy:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at groovy.ui.ConsoleView$_run_closure1.doCall(ConsoleView.groovy:62)
    at groovy.ui.ConsoleView$_run_closure1.doCall(ConsoleView.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.dispatchNodeCall(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:899)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:791)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.invokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:511)
    at groovy.util.FactoryInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1322)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:177)
    at groovy.ui.ConsoleView.run(ConsoleView.groovy:59)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1181)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport.build(FactoryBuilderSupport.java:1164)
    at groovy.util.FactoryBuilderSupport$build$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at groovy.ui.Console.run(Console.groovy:308)
    at groovy.ui.Console$run$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at groovy.ui.Console.run(Console.groovy:271)
    at groovy.ui.Console$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at groovy.ui.Console.main(Console.groovy:205)
    ... 6 more

    enter code here
```

My system is:

```
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.16 JVM: 1.8.0_222 Vendor: Private Build OS: Linux
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a known issue reported in [Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/groovy), [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/groovy/+bug/1842928) and [Groovy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8253) issues trackers.

Issue has been fixed in Groovy version `2.6.0-alpha-1`. The fix was backported (see [Debian patch](https://salsa.debian.org/java-team/groovy/-/blob/debian/2.4.17-2/debian/patches/13_GROOVY_8253.patch)) in Ubuntu package version `2.4.17-4ubuntu1` and Debian package version `2.4.17-2`.

In Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 LTS, Groovy package version available is `2.4.16-1ubuntu1~18.04.1` (and `2.4.16-2` in Debian).
Version `2.4.17-4ubuntu1` is available in Ubuntu Focal 20.04 LTS (currently `2.4.20-1` in Debian testing).

So I guess the easiest solution for you might be to **upgrade to Ubuntu Focal 20.04 LTS** version.

An alternative would be to install only groovy package from Focal 20.04 and keep others packages unmodified (i.e. keep version provided by Ubuntu Bionic 18.04). Such solution involve package pinning. You can read more about it in [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto), [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration) or in this excellent [Debian administrator's handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html#sect.apt.priorities).